# Need to fill entire remaining div

Tags: css, html

The background color *black* fills the padding area only *As show below* and I need it to cover the whole div area.

[image: the black area is padding only!!]

[Html Code](http://pastebin.com/EJTDPBG8)

[Css Code](http://pastebin.com/vmtKzyqQ)

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you floats here is my suggestion make it **Flex**:

```
.core {padding:50px;margin:0 auto;max-width:1000px; display: flex;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nwtttmqk/

You can also do inline....but flex is....more flexible (and modern)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that when you `float` an element using css `float:left` or `float:right`, the parent container will lose it's natural height that is defined by its children.

You should read [this post](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) about `floats` and `clears`